# Ubuntu installation failure - Unable to install grub - Locked-NVram

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, bootloader, boot-repair

230612 adding image of sure start settings [Image of sure start bios settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXk3S.jpg)

230611 Updating post with additional changes tried in BIOS/UEFI settings

Having issues when trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.2 (desktop) on my refurbed mini PC:
HP EliteDesk 800 G3 DM
i5-6500T
8 GB RAM
240 GB SSD

No dual boot, only want Ubuntu.

I created a boot-loader on a USB stick that launches fine. Double checked and the USB-stick is GPT formated. When reaching the end of installation process I received an error saying:

```
Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda
Executing `grub-install /dev/sda` failed.
This is a fatal error.
```

I've tried changing the settings in BIOS to both these options:

```
Legacy Support Disable and Secure Boot Disable
Legacy Support Enable and Secure Boot Disable
Removed fast boot option from BIOS.
Clearing all Secure Boot Keys - 
Removed HP Firmware Runtime Intrustion Prevention and Detection (BIOS SureStart)
Removed Dynamic Runtime Scanning of Boot Block
Resetted CMOS (twice)
Reset to factory defaults and apply changes again
```

Tried booting from disk both in UEFI and Legacy after installation - UEFI gets stuck on boot screen and Legacy can't find boot image (assuming this depends on me installing Ubuntu on UEFI).

When running the boot-repair-disk through the terminal in **Try Ubuntu** mode I receive the following output:

```
An error occurred during the repair.
Error: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr). Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

Please write on a paper the following URL:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GPx5PKK9hy/


In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com
```

Have also tried reinstalling Ubuntu a couple of times.

Edit 230529: In addition to the above I have now also tried the following:

1. Resetting the CMOS, reinstalled, disk repair -> same errors, Unable to install GRUB, NVram locked
2. Updated to latest HP bios 2.46, reisntalled ubuntu, disk repair -> same errors, Unable to install GRUB, NVram locked

Not sure what else I can try. Any other version of Ubuntu that might work better? Any way to manually install GRUB by-passing the NVram locked issue?

Pastebin from latest boot repair (updated 230611):

```
boot-repair-4ppa2056                                              [20230611_1832]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================






Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
sda2,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file


Mount sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi
No sda2/boot/efi/efi/ ubuntu/mint folder

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda2/etc/default/grub

======================== Reinstall the grub-efi of sda2 ========================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.1
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 000E
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 000E,000B,0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007,0008,0009,000F
Boot0000  Startup Menu  FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)....ISPH
Boot0001  System Information    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0002  Bios Setup    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0003  3rd Party Option ROM Management   FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0004  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0005  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0006  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0007  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0008  Boot Menu FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0009  HP Recovery   FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot000B* SAMSUNG MZ7LN256HAJQ-000H1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(1,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000C* IPV6 Network - Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(186024278b1d,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000D* IPV4 Network - Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(186024278b1d,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000E* Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 E0D55E6CE77C1731F9B60656    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(18,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000F  Network Boot  FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0012  Generic USB Storage   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(3,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0013  Generic USB Storage   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(4,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0014  PHIYO USBTB3-12 123456789010  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(16,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0015  PHIYO USBTB3-12 123456789010  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(17,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0016  PHIYO USBTB3-12 123456789010  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(19,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0017  PHIYO USBTB3-12 123456789010  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(20,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 uname -r
5.19.0-32-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot open `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi': No such file or directory.
Exit code: 1
Error: no grub*.efi generated for Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 /sbin/grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --recheck
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
/sbin/grub-install: error: cannot open `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi': No such file or directory.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 /sbin/grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --no-nvram
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
/sbin/grub-install: error: cannot open `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi': No such file or directory.
--no-nvram exit code: 1 Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 000E
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 000E,000B,0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007,0008,0009,000F
Boot0000  Startup Menu  FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)....ISPH
Boot0001  System Information    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0002  Bios Setup    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0003  3rd Party Option ROM Management   FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0004  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0005  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0006  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0007  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0008  Boot Menu FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0009  HP Recovery   FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot000B* SAMSUNG MZ7LN256HAJQ-000H1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(1,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000C* IPV6 Network - Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(186024278b1d,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000D* IPV4 Network - Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(186024278b1d,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000E* Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 E0D55E6CE77C1731F9B60656    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(18,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000F  Network Boot  FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0012  Generic USB Storage   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(3,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0013  Generic USB Storage   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(4,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0014  PHIYO USBTB3-12 123456789010  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(16,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0015  PHIYO USBTB3-12 123456789010  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(17,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0016  PHIYO USBTB3-12 123456789010  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(19,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0017  PHIYO USBTB3-12 123456789010  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(20,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Error: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr). Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-32-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
cp: error reading '/mnt/boot-sav/sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg': Input/output error
cp: error reading '/mnt/boot-sav/sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg': Input/output error
cat: /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: Input/output error

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

An error occurred during the repair.
Error: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr). Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

Locked-NVram detected.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda1 has 
                       7811072 sectors.. But according to the info from the 
                       partition table, it has 1048575 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdb and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on sda2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: HD Graphics 530 from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: P21 Ver. 02.46(2.46) from HP
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 000E
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 000E,000B,0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007,0008,0009,000F
Boot0000  Startup Menu  FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)....ISPH
Boot0001  System Information    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0002  Bios Setup    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0003  3rd Party Option ROM Management   FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0004  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0005  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0006  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0007  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0008  Boot Menu FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0009  HP Recovery   FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot000B* SAMSUNG MZ7LN256HAJQ-000H1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(1,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000C* IPV6 Network - Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(186024278b1d,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000D* IPV4 Network - Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(186024278b1d,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000E* Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 E0D55E6CE77C1731F9B60656    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(18,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000F  Network Boot  FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0012  Generic USB Storage   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(3,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0013  Generic USB Storage   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(4,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0014  PHIYO USBTB3-12 123456789010  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(16,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0015  PHIYO USBTB3-12 123456789010  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(17,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0016  PHIYO USBTB3-12 123456789010  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(19,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0017  PHIYO USBTB3-12 123456789010  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(20,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH

bfd3f5550a8a28a1021abe2b838e3b6a   sda1/BOOT/grubx64.efi
dc3c47be2f78a78e5e57d097ae6c5c84   sda1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sda1/BOOT/BOOTx64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk identifier: 96F12D4F-7885-4E13-BFED-53426A3F18CD
        Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
sda1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
sda2  1050624 500117503 499066880  238G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 28.87 GiB, 30995907072 bytes, 60538881 sectors
Disk identifier: A0891D7E-B930-4513-94D9-F629DBD637B2
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdb1       64  9613459  9613396  4.6G Microsoft basic data
sdb2  9613460  9623527    10068  4.9M EFI System
sdb3  9623528  9624127      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdb4  9625600 60538817 50913218 24.3G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:256GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA SAMSUNG MZ7LN256:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:256GB:256GB:ext4::;
sdb:31.0GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:Kingston DataTraveler 3.0:;
1:32.8kB:4922MB:4922MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:4922MB:4927MB:5155kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:4927MB:4928MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:4928MB:31.0GB:26.1GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
├─sda1 vfat     56CC-DEF5                            67426988-6317-42b4-9c40-4530011a5cf6                          EFI System Partition
└─sda2 ext4     c536fd40-b9ca-4759-88d1-b3bd6ef6b1a1 b193bf07-b32f-4eb8-81df-10f1f104182c                          
sdb    iso9660  2023-02-23-04-13-44-00                                                    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1 iso9660  2023-02-23-04-13-44-00               a0891d7e-b930-4513-94d8-f629dbd637b2 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdb2 vfat     F7DB-4D56                            a0891d7e-b930-4513-94db-f629dbd637b2 ESP                      Appended2
├─sdb3                                               a0891d7e-b930-4513-94da-f629dbd637b2                          Gap1
└─sdb4 ext4     9ef377e8-76c4-4b9c-8c26-e4738a2dd8df 0d7ad038-c798-234d-b090-1211e3d3c043 writable                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-09-09.0/crash]  22.5G   0% /var/crash
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-09-09.0/log]    22.5G   0% /var/log
/dev/sda1                                                     491.1M  87% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2                                                     212.2G   4% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================


==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

====================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   c536fd40-b9ca-4759-88d1-b3bd6ef6b1a1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-32-generic   c536fd40-b9ca-4759-88d1-b3bd6ef6b1a1
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=c536fd40-b9ca-4759-88d1-b3bd6ef6b1a1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=56CC-DEF5  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 236.426387787 = 253.860900864  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 236.426387787 = 253.860900864  boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-32-generic                 1
 237.169620514 = 254.658940928  boot/initrd.img                                1
 237.169620514 = 254.658940928  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-32-generic              1
 237.169620514 = 254.658940928  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec  2  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec  2  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Dec  2  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec  2  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec  2  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Sep 20  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec  2  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec  2  2022 41_custom
```

What else can I do here? Anything manually I can try?

Comment: Do you have an ESP - efi system partition FAT32 with boot,esp flags? HP is only one that does not support use of efibootmgr which grub & we use to update UEFI boot entries. Have not seen one clear solution to Locked NVram issue. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482909

Comment: Checked the partitions with gparted boot disk and I have one partition /dev/sda1 named EFI system partition, FAT32, 512MB flagged boot, esp and another /dev/sda2, no name, ext4, 237gb, no flags. How can I work around this issue?

Comment: Make sure you UEFI does not have any settings that lock or secure ESP. Some have a separate setting from UEFI secure boot.

Comment: Additional testing done up until now:
1. Reset CMOS by pushing button on motherboard, re/installed Ubunutu - Same errors, Unable to install GRUB + NVRam locked
2. Updated BIOS to latest version - Same errors, Unable to install GRUB + NVRam locked

Comment: Another HP with locked RAM issue. You need to review UEFI settings: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482555&page=2

Comment: Still working on this issue.
New attempts with no luck:
- Removing TPM and clearing TPM (TPM State = off, TPM Device = Available)
- Clearing all Secure Boot Keys
- Tried installing Mint instead of Ubuntu
- Removed HP Firmware Runtime Intrustion Prevention and Detection (BIOS SureStart)

All with same issues. 

What bios options can still be a possible explanation?
- BIOS SureStart?
- System Options? (Turboboost, multi-processor, M.2 SDD, M.2 WLAN/BT, Allow PCIe/PCI Serr?
- Reset Secure Boot Keys to defalts?

Really running out of options to try here. Anyone with any new ideas?

Comment: I have one possibility to "Import Custom Secure Boot keys". Can this be used in some way?
Option ROM Launch Policy? This says "All UEFI" and is grayed out.
Remote Management Options?

Comment: If UEFI secure boot if off, you do not need to add keys. What is SureStart? Do not have HP and have not seen that before. Often resetting UEFI requires you to go back and redo all the changes you need again.

Comment: Added image to post on the sure start settings. Yeah I did redo all settings after resetting cmos and factory resetting bios with no luck.

Comment: Is there any other distribution that might be more HP friendly and work better? Manjaro?

Comment: If able to boot live installer, you can use an external SSD and put a full install on it. I have multiple flash drives with full installs, but they are slow. But recently got a SSD and it is almost as fast as an internal SSD using USB3 to SATA adapter. You do have to gpt partition in advance to have ESP on external drive for booting external drive. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 One of the work arounds in bug report. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator &

Answer (score 0):

Following this article to reset the CMOS using ubuntu terminal solved my problem. I installed ubuntu on my flash then i boot into the flash. After that, choose "try or install ubuntu" then "try ubuntu". Then i followed the steps found in [this article](https://devicetests.com/resetting-bios-ubuntu#google_vignette)